# Windows phone 8 XMLParseException

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am programming my first Windows phone 8.0 app. Now i want to have a map on one of the pages. But always comes the following Error:

> "TaskHost.exe" (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain):
>   "C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen
>   wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur
>   eigenen Code" ist aktiviert. "TaskHost.exe" (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):
>   "C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll" geladen. Das
>   Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und
>   die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert. "TaskHost.exe" (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):
>   "C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll" geladen. Das Laden von
>   Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die
>   Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert. "TaskHost.exe" (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):
>   "C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll" geladen. Das Laden von
>   Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die
>   Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert. "TaskHost.exe" (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):
>   "C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll" geladen. Das Laden von Symbolen
>   wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die Debugoption "Nur
>   eigenen Code" ist aktiviert. "TaskHost.exe" (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):
>   "C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll" geladen. Das Laden von
>   Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die
>   Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert. "TaskHost.exe" (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):
>   "C:\Data\Programs{5C2EF028-5C31-4B76-92FF-0E4CDCDC1C27}\Install\PhoneApp2.DLL"
>   geladen. Symbole wurden geladen. "TaskHost.exe" (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):
>   "C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll" geladen. Das Laden von
>   Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die
>   Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert. "TaskHost.exe" (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):
>   "C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll" geladen. Das
>   Laden von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und
>   die Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert. "TaskHost.exe" (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):
>   "C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Maps.ni.dll" geladen. Das Laden
>   von Symbolen wurde übersprungen. Das Modul ist optimiert, und die
>   Debugoption "Nur eigenen Code" ist aktiviert. "TaskHost.exe" (CLR
>   C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain):
>   "C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll" geladen. Das
>   Modul wurde ohne Symbole erstellt. In
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException ist eine Ausnahme vom Typ
>   "System.Windows.ni.dll" aufgetreten, die nicht vor einer
>   verwalteten/systemeigenen Grenze behandelt wurde In
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException ist eine Ausnahme vom Typ
>   "Microsoft.Phone.Maps.ni.dll" aufgetreten, die nicht vor einer
>   verwalteten/systemeigenen Grenze behandelt wurde In
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException ist eine Ausnahme vom Typ
>   "mscorlib.ni.dll" aufgetreten, die nicht vor einer
>   verwalteten/systemeigenen Grenze behandelt wurde In
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException ist eine Ausnahme vom Typ
>   "mscorlib.ni.dll" aufgetreten, die nicht vor einer
>   verwalteten/systemeigenen Grenze behandelt wurde In
>   MS.Internal.NativeParseException ist eine Ausnahme vom Typ
>   "System.Windows.ni.dll" aufgetreten, die nicht vor einer
>   verwalteten/systemeigenen Grenze behandelt wurde Eine Ausnahme (erste
>   Chance) des Typs "System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException" ist in
>   System.Windows.ni.dll aufgetreten.

I made a new project with only the map to see where the problem is. But it doesn't help anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's because, you don't grant your app the rights to use the maps function.

Just open your **WMAppManifest.xml**:

- Open the *Capabilities* tab
- Check *`ID_CAP_MAP`*